# Selecting Polygons of one layer with information from table using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, select-by-attribute

I have two 2 datasets:

1. A shapefile with many polygons. They all have an ID.
2. A table (.csv) that has one column with IDs.

I need to select all Polygons in 1) that are mentioned in the column of table (2)).

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. Select by location does not work, because I cannot display the table (because its just a table).

Comment: You add your csv table to the map document convert it to a proper table then build a RELATE between the table and your spatial dataset. Suggest you explore the help file on relates, that is how you pass a selection between tables.

Comment: I managed. The problem was that the table was not editable really. So PolyGeos "convert it to a proper table" kind of helped. My solution was:
1) Copy Rows
2) Add column with value 1
3) Join this table to the big dataset
4) Select all rows with a 1 in the new column

Done. 
Thank you!!